# How to search by Start date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, search

I want to allow the user to search by just start date. I came across this but I don't know how to modify it so that if the user enters 7 it will retrieve all July start date data or any month on the date 7.

Example: User enters 7 and search, output will be : 7/2/2015 or 2/7/2015.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCity FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtFrom.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtTo.Text, new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 7, 1).  Entering datetime by country culture (month-day vs day-month) isn't simple because you need to add to the code the country.  Instead make the user enter in universal time which is yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @jdweng sorry i dont get it. i wanted to do a search then the data will retrieve and bind to gridview . how can i change the sqlcommand?

Comment: You mean, if user enters 7 then your application should retrieve all records of July month ?

Comment: What's your orderdate field type ? Is it varchar or datetime ?

Comment: You don't need to change the sqlcommand, just how you enter the parameters.  Right now you are using Convert.ToDateTime() method to get a DataTime object from a string.  I'm recommending using the DataTime constructor which takes numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear so I suppose you need to have only those order dates which contain the date equal to value given by user or month equal to value given by user. If my assumption is correct you can try below:

```
for (var intCount = 0; intCount < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    var dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount]["OrderDate"]);
    if (!dateTime.Day.ToString().Equals("7") && !dateTime.Month.ToString().Equals("7")) //Replace 7 with user input
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount].Delete();
    }
}
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

And then populate you grid with ds.

But again I am bit curious about why you are not doing this operation on data base side itself. Because bringing all the data to code via network and then doing filtering operation on that will slow down your application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a SQL question to me. You may want to try the `DATEPART` SQL command. If the user enters a number into `txtFrom`, then you don't convert that to a date for comparison. You could set the `SqlCommand` to:

```
"SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipName, ShipCity 
   FROM Orders 
  WHERE DATEPART(month, OrderDate) BETWEEN @From AND @To
     OR DATEPART(day, OrderDate) BETWEEN @From AND @To "
```

If they haven't entered a value in `txtTo`, so just a start date, you could do

```
var from = txtFrom.Text;
var to = txtTo.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(to))
{
    to = from;
}
```

That would trap anything with a month of 7 or a day of 7, if they entered a 7 into the From field.